# Cookies doesnt retain after session ends (Wampserver, Chrome, Windows)

Tags: php, cookies, wamp

I'm trying to set a value to a cookie but after I close the browser the cookie dies. When I create it and check the Chrome settings it says "Expires: 
At the end of the browsing session".

This is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['cookie'])) {
            setcookie("doma", $_GET['cookie'],  time() + (86400 * 30 * 365), '/');
            header ("Location: index.php");
    }


    if(!isset($_COOKIE["doma"]) && !isset($_SESSION["logg"])) {
        header ("Location: login.php?iniciar=1");
    } else {

?>
```

Comment: you should change your browser settings and make an alert to users, you can't keep the cookies if the browser is set to delete them

Comment: Every other cookies from other sites works well, and the same happen in Firefox, IE and Opera.